# How to dynamically set a JLabel text

Tags: java, html, swing, variables, settext

```
int variable = 100;

label = new JLabel("<html><font color=red>variable</font><html>");
```

How do I make this display "100" on screen and not "variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By building a `String` with it included:-

```
label = new JLabel("<html><font color=red>" + variable + "</font><html>");
```

This will output `<html><font color=red>100</font><html>` (well, in a label it will be [html](/questions/tagged/html) formatted)
 The reason yours didn't work is because almost anything inside quotes is treated as a `String` so adding a variable in there is just the same as adding the name of the variable.

**Additionally**

This will also work for objects, not just primitive types like `int` by calling their `toString()` method and adding the output from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method:

```
label = new JLabel(String.format("<html><font color=red>%d</font><html>", variable));
```